# Why do the Go-generated protobuf files contain mutex locks?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, mutex

While working and generating protobuf stubs in go I stumbled upon this interesting issue.

Whenever I try and copy a message's struct by value I get this warning:

> call of state.world.script.HandleEvent copies lock value: throne/server/messages.PlayerDialogeStatus contains google.golang.org/protobuf/internal/impl.MessageState contains sync.Mutex copylocks

While **I understand why copying a mutex lock by value is wrong**, I started wondering why are they even there in the first place.

And thus my question: Why does the go generated protobuf files contain mutex locks placed on the message structs, specifically on the `MessageState` struct?

Or alternatively: What is the goal of the mutex lock placed in the `MessageState` struct found on generated protobuf message structs?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [impl.MessageState](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/protobuf/internal/impl#MessageState) is embedded in concrete messages only, not in the generated structs that implement a proto message.

It specifically embeds the three [pragmas](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/protobuf/internal/pragma): `NoUnkeyedLiterals`, `DoNotCompare`, and `DoNotCopy`.

The last one, [DoNotCopy](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/protobuf/internal/pragma#DoNotCopy) is a zero-sized array of `sync.Mutex`. The sole purpose is to have `go vet` complain loudly about shallow copies, as described in the comment:

> DoNotCopy can be embedded in a struct to help prevent shallow copies.
> This does not rely on a Go language feature, but rather a special case
> within the vet checker.

The summary of it all: `impl.MessageState` is **not supposed to be copied and the mutex is there only to catch copying**. If you do so, it is because you are using something the wrong way.

Comment: _If you do so, it is because you are using something the wrong way._

Can you expand on that? What is the downside of copying it? What sorts of problems does it invite?

Comment: I also would like to learn what I was doing wrong by passing proto structures by value. This change caused massive inconvenience in upgrading to the newest version of proto in our project. I prefer not to deal with nils if possible and rely on the empty default value.

Comment: In addition to Jeff Widman's good question. If one wishes to copy the message state, what is the "right" way to go about it?

Answer (score 12):

As far as I can tell, there are three reasons the Go protobuf API includes the [DoNotCopy](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/protobuf/internal/pragma#DoNotCopy) mutex:

1. The maintainers may wish to change the internal representation in the future, in a way that will not work with shallow copies.
2. It is theoretically unsafe to mix atomic and non-atomic accesses to the same memory. The protobuf structs contains an internal field that is usually read and written with an atomic access. Calling `msg.Marshal()` on a message, then overwriting it with `*msg = MyMessage{...}` mixes atomic and non-atomic accesses. Even if this works with today's implementation on x86, there is no guarantee this will work on other systems in the future. (See [a long Go issue about this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/5045#issuecomment-252730563)).
3. If you call `ProtoReflect()` on a message, then later overwrite the message, it will crash, since the ProtoReflect() result relies on the internal reflection pointer ([original issue](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/1089)):

```golang
d := &durationpb.Duration{Seconds: 1}
protoreflectMessage := d.ProtoReflect()
fmt.Printf("protoreflectMessage.Interface()=%v\n", protoreflectMessage.Interface())
*d = durationpb.Duration{Seconds: 2}
fmt.Printf("protoreflectMessage.Interface()=%v\n", protoreflectMessage.Interface())
```

This crashes with:

```
protoreflectMessage.Interface()=seconds:1
panic: invalid nil message info; this suggests memory corruption due to a race or shallow copy on the message struct
```